# What do the preferences keyframing options actually mean?

Tags: animation, customization

[image]

The reason I'm asking: It seems that I've fumbled too much with these options and weird things happen.I couldn't find any meaningful explanation in the [docs](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences/Editing).

What do these options influence, especially on keying and editing actions (poselibs)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- **Auto Keyframing**:
  Enable it and create a new scene, add a cube for example, then move the cube, scroll to a different frame on the timeline, and move the cube again. Keyframes will automatically be created for the transformations (inserts a *LocRotScale* group if you e.g. use <kbd>G</kbd> to translate the object).
  You can find the same toggle in the timeline header (icon only, red circle).
- **Show Auto Keying Warning**:
  If Auto Keyframing is active, a notice will appear in the upper-right corner of the 3D View *during* transformations, to inform/remind the user, that new keyframes are going to be added (if one confirms the transformation).
- **Only Insert Available**:
  Keyframes will be added to existing F-Curves only, and no new groups are implicitly created for you. So manually keyframe e.g. *Location* once, then change time and move the object around. Keyframes will be created for its translation, but not for rotation or scale, because rotation and scale don't have keyframes / F-Curves yet.
- **Visual Keying**:
  From blender wiki:

  > This is to be used with objects or bones that have
  >   certain constraints that can affect the key values. For example,
  >   setting a key on an object with a Copy Location constraint would
  >   normally set the key for it’s unconstrained location. Enabling this
  >   option causes the key to be set for the constrained location.
- **Only Insert Needed**:

  > Will add keys only when needed (i.e. only to F-Curves controlling
  >   properties that are changing).

For completeness: the documentation on [*Timeline*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/Timeline) has more detailed information.

Comment: *Only Insert Needed* still missing, anyone? @stacker: I marked my answer as CW, 'cause I knew it was incomplete (missing 2/5 of what was asked for) and with room to improve my 3.

Comment: @stacker: that quote for "only insert needed" is pretty meaningless... doesn't really explain, and are there even IPO curves in Blender newer than 2.49? Don't we use F-Curves now?

Comment: I understand it this way: A keyframe will only be inserted when a property e.g. loc or rot is actually changed.

Comment: This is something that looked like a bug to me but I finally figured it out. Let's say you're animating a footstep. Set xyz location keys at frame 1, go to frame 10 and with 'Only insert needed' enabled move the foot on the x axis. Rather counter-intuitively keys are set for all xyz, not just x. However to to frame 5 and try it again. This time a key is inserted only on the channel that changed. 

Ie it only works between existing keys. Seems like a design limitation to me as I'd expect it to apply to unkeyed space, but once you know it's still useful.