# "No suitable context info for active keying set"

Tags: animation, keyframes

I m trying to make an animation using keyframes.When I press on "I"and location nd rotation,this error comes up no suitable context info for active keying set.
Plz provide a solution in a simple manner.I am new to this,so I need a descriptive answer.I need to know exactly what to do,what to press,where to find.

Comment: please provide a screenshot so we can see what you are doing and some more details

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be related to to **Keying Set** ... see [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html).

---

Try to delete under Scene Properties > Keying Sets > *Keying Set* (if accidentally created)

[image]

or clean under Timeline editor > Keying menu > *Active Keying Set* slot

[image]

... if not your case provide more info as Chris suggested.

Some useful links ...
[What is a keying set and how does it fit into the animation workflow?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7636)
[Why can I not keyframe this armature?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31672)