# Difference between visual and normal keyframes

Tags: animation

I was looking at this question:

[What do the preferences keyframing options actually mean?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6763/what-do-the-preferences-keyframing-options-actually-mean/6774#6774)

I still can't figure out what the difference is between a visual LocRotScale, and just a normal LocRotScale.  An in depth explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 20):

The following cube has a limit location set to (0,0,0) when you move the cube its position in the viewport don't change while the location info in the transform panel shows this change:

[image]

this is the case for all constraints they won't change what is displayed on the properties panel while they change the visual properties ( loc, rot, scale)

[image]

- so you if you keyframe the location you'll store (1.938, 0.411, 1.286) for the current frame
- while if you keyframe the visual location you'll store (0, 0, 0)